# How to use a custom Modal to edit the fullcalendar event name instead of the default javascript prompt

Tags: php, html, ajax, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar that inserts data into a database table ondrag and drop event.The fullcalendar also edits the event name onclick and saves the new event name to the database.Onclick a prompt dialog is used to edit the event name.I recently added a custom boostrap modal popup to my fullcalendar to display the events and edit the event name but i cant seem to figure out how to edit the event name and save it to the database using the custom modal.This only seems to work when i use the javascript prompt.
This is my edit event code Using javascript Prompt:

```
 var title = prompt('Event Title:', event.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false}});
     if (title){
          event.title = title; console.log('type=changetitle&title='+title+'&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&numb='+numb+'&start='+start+'&end='+end+'&eventid='+event.id);
                      $.ajax({
                            url: 'process.php',
                            data: 'type=changetitle&title='+title+'&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&numb='+numb+'&start='+start+'&end='+end+'&eventid='+event.id,
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(response){    
                                if(response.status == 'success')                            
                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                            },
                            error: function(e){
                                alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                  }
            },
```

Now i have added a custom boostrap modal to display the events.but cant seem to figure out how to edit the event name using the custom modal.

Heres my code using a custom modal onclick event:

eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log(event.id);

```
$('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
    $('#modalName').html(event.name);
    $('#modalEmail').html(event.email);
    $('#modalNumb').html(event.numb);
    $("#modalDate1").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
    $('#modalDate2').html(moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
    $('#dialog').modal("show") 


         var title = modal('Event Title:', event.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false}});

          if (title){
```

.......//the rest of the code is the same as above

And here is the html code for the modal:

```
  <div class="modal" id="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"></h4>
          <input class="modalTitle" type="text" id="Edit"/>
        <div class="external-event bg-fuchsia" id="status"></div>  
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
        Client:<h3 id="modalName"></h3>
          <hr>
          Email:<h3 id="modalEmail"></h3>
          <hr>
          Number:<h3 id="modalNumb"></h3>
          <hr>
          CheckIn:<h3 id="modalDate1"></h3>
           <hr>
           CheckOut:<h3 id="modalDate2"></h3>
      </div>
        <button type="button primary" class="btn btn-danger" aria-hidden="true" id="true">Save</button> 
           <button type="button primary" class="btn btn-danger" aria-hidden="true" id="false">Cancel</button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I basically need to be able to edit the event using the custom modal instead of a prompt.Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cache the event in a variable that you can have access after the modal opens and attach to the save button a click event that updates the fullcalendar event to your database.

something like this

```
var myEvent;
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) { 
    myEvent= event;
    // code
}
....
$( '#true' ).click(function(){
    myEvent.title = $( '#Edit' ).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        data: 'type=changetitle&title='+myEvent.title+'&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&numb='+numb+'&start='+start+'&end='+end+'&eventid='+event.id,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){    
            if(response.status == 'success')                            
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',myEvent);
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The events are already being saved to my db,and edit event name also works but using prompt.What i need is how to edit the event name using modal <input> with the specific values

Comment: You can get the title from the input value, i have update my answer

Comment: Thanks,got it...much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I used this is a way for me to get all the required data from my modal and back to the controller via AJAX, even has validation and alerts for server messages.

```
  dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#LeaveStart').val(date.format('DD-MM-YYYY 00:00'));
        $('#LeaveFinish').val(date.format('DD-MM-YYYY 23:59'));
        $('#popupEventForm').modal('show');
        $('#myform').validate({
            rules: {
                StaffID: {
                    required: true
                },
                SelectRole: {
                    required: true
                },
                customdescription: {
                    required: true
                },
                SicknessType: {
                    required: true
                },
                SicknessSubType: {
                    required: true
                },
                StartDate: {
                    required: true
                },
                EndDate: {
                    required: true
                },
                EventStatus: {
                    required: true
                },
            },
            /*MESSAGES*/
            messages: {
                StaffID: {
                    required: "Please select staff member"
                },
                SelectRole: {
                    required: "Please select a role"
                },
                customdescription: {
                    required: "Please enter leave details"
                },
                SicknessType: {
                    required: "Please select a leave type"
                },
                SicknessSubType: {
                    required: "Please select a leave sub type"
                },
                StartDate: {
                    required: "Please Enter a start date"
                },
                EndDate: {
                    required: "Please Enter an end date"
                },
                EventStatus: {
                    required: "Please confirm a status"
                },
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var dataRow = {
                    'Id': $('#id').val(),
                    'Subject': $('#title').val(),
                    'Description': $('#customdescription').val(),
                    'StartTime': $('#LeaveStart').val(),
                    'EndTime': $('#LeaveFinish').val(),
                    'SelectRole': $('#SelectRole').val(),
                    'ETADType': $('#SicknessType').val(),
                    'ETADSubType': $('#SicknessSubType').val(),
                    'StaffID': $('#StaffID').val(),
                    'EventStatus': $('#EventStatus').val(),
                    'AllRoles': $('#AllRoles').is(':checked'),
                    'AllDay': $('#AllDay').is(':checked'),
                    'isAMLeave': $('#AM').is(':checked'),
                    'isPMLeave': $('#PM').is(':checked'),
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/BookingTwo/SaveEvent",
                    data: dataRow,
                    success: function () {
                        $("#myform")[0].reset();
                        ClearPopupFormValues();
                        $('#popupEventForm').modal('hide');
                    },
                    statusCode: {
                        201: function (reponose) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            $('#alert').addClass('alert alert-success').removeClass('alert-warning');
                            $("#alert").removeClass("hidden");
                            $("P").replaceWith("Success - Event Created")
                            $("#alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                                $('#alert').addClass("hidden");
                            })
                        },
                        500: function (reponse) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            $("#alert").removeClass("hidden");
                            $('#popupEventForm').modal('hide');
                            $("P").replaceWith("The Error Been forwarded to system admin")
                            $("#alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                                $('#alert').addClass("hidden");
                            })
                        },
                        400: function (reponse) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            $("#alert").removeClass("hidden");
                            $('#popupEventForm').modal('hide');
                            $("P").replaceWith("Duration Service returned 0 - Please Ensure Correct Shift Days are selected. Record NOT Created.")
                            $("#alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                                $('#alert').addClass("hidden");
                            })
                        },
                        409: function (reponse) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            ClearPopupFormValues();
                            $("#alert").removeClass("hidden");
                            $('#popupEventForm').modal('hide');
                            $("P").replaceWith(reponse.messages)
                            $("#alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
                                $('#alert').addClass("hidden");
                            })
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    },
});
```

Comment: No problem, ive spent a lot of time with Full Calendar lately, if you need any help let me know, although im using .net MVC framework.